# How to add a TextField object in list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to add a TextField object in a list but i have a error "The argument type 'PlayerItem' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextField'.

I created a TextField list (`_playerList`):

```
List<TextField> _playerList = new List();
```

I created a class to create TextField object:

```
class PlayerItem extends StatelessWidget {

  //constructor
  PlayerItem();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
        hintText: "Player",
        counterText: "",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When i tried to add a item in list i have a error:

```
 _playerList.add(new PlayerItem()),
```

Comment: Convert your list type to `List<PlayerItem>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected type error.

You declared your list as `List<TextField>` and try to insert `PlayerItem`.
The consequence of this is that you should type your list using `PlayerItem`:

```dart
List<PlayerItem> _playerList = <PlayerItem>[];
```

Alternatively, you could also use a more generic type, i.e. a super type of both `TextField` and `PlayerItem` which could be `Widget` for example:

```dart
List<Widget> _playerList = <Widget>[];
```